# Stuck in compositing! Only video renders nothing else!

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm new to this, but used the compositer and a node trees to put images keyframed in the nodes and text over the video clips but none of it shows when I render it out, I've checked the boxes under render menu bolth compositing and sequencer I'm lost and don't have a clue how to fix it.... unless I did it all wrong..... hope not.
I used image nodes as inputs for all images set to single image
Then to a transform nod to a mix node which I have tons of them, all Keyframed, it all works fine in viewer node but all I have is video when I render it. Nothing else shows.

Comment: If you are using the compositor don't check the box for sequencer

Comment: but you did use a "compositor" node, right? not just the viewer (that outputs nothing)... I did a similar setup (both compositor and sequencer checkboxes enabled), and it renders the mixed images... not sure of what you mean with "all I have is video when I render it", though...

Comment: Please post images that show your compositing nodes, render settings and any other relevant information

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a video strip in the Video Sequencer. This clip was there when I initially edited the video before Montion tracking. So only the frame from that video was always rendered. As another post [suggests](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/275216/57735), you can disable Video Sequencer in Output properties -> Post Processing -> untick Sequencer