# Blender 3.3 only rendering the video editor

Tags: rendering, animation

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to render my viewport animation (with key frames to move a model), it always starts rendering my video editor instead. Now the video editor does have some videos and images in it, so I tried deleting everything inside it still didn't work. Then I tried rendering a photo, it still only rendered a photo of a frame from the video editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the video editor is completely empty it shouldn't affect the render, anyway you can disable the VSE completely in the properties panel, output properties, post processing tab.

[image]